# How to get rid of the “scanning for btrfs file systems” at start-up?

Tags: boot, btrfs

At start-up, I see the message *Scanning for btrfs file systems*. How can I get rid of it?

I have tried to remove the package with `sudo apt-get purge btrfs-tools`, but it just shows a blank screen before the splash screen while Ubuntu is booting.

Comment: Why would you want to do it? What is the real problem?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78535/how-to-get-rid-of-the-scanning-for-btrfs-file-systems-at-start-up

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/492108/how-to-disable-scanning-btrfs-filesystem-at-system-startup