# how to disable 'scanning btrfs filesystem' at system startup

Tags: 14.04, startup, btrfs, scanning

After upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04, I get a message "`scanning for btrfs file systems`" at starting-up. I don't have any BTRFS filesystem. It delays the booting for about 15 seconds.

I tried to :

1. blacklist the brtfs module in `/etc/modprobe.d`
2. remove `btrfs-tools`
3. renamed the executable `/sbin/btrfs` to p.e `/sbin/btrfs.save`

Now i get a blank screen for about 15 seconds until the splash screen appears.

Answer (score 4):

Btrfs isn’t too much stable to be used as deafult file-system. Most Linux distributions, probable all, are still using ext4 as primary file-system. So, you can completely remove it from your computer. Try the given command:

```
sudo apt-get purge btrfs-tools
```

This command will remove btrfs-tools from your computer. You may need to wait some minutes to complete the process. Your initramfs should be updated automatically but if not happen, do it by this command:

```
sudo update-initramfs -ukall
```

Then make a grub update:

```
sudo update-grub
```

All is well. Now make a restart. Hope your Ubuntu will start successfully this time.

Reference: http://www.ugcoder.com/disable-scanning-for-btrfs-file-systems-in-ubuntu/

Let me know if you have some questions still.

Comment: Could you please include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link as a reference.

Comment: Well, ext4 doesn't look too stable either: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=EXT4-Linux-4.19-Corruption  better using ext3 ;-)

Comment: This can work but not if you have apps that have btrfs-tools as a dependency that you need.  see my post in unix/linux.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/630482/201387

Answer (score 4):

On my system **it is not the btrfs-scan** which is causing the system to hang at boot. Instead there is a background-process trying to figure out where to find the swap-partition. My system has a SSD and plenty of RAM so it has no swap. This causes the background-process which is looking for a swap-partition to run into the void.

To change this, you can do the following:

1. In the file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` change the statement `RESUME=...` into `RESUME=none`
2. After this update initramfs: `sudo update-initramfs -ukall`

Comment: alternatively you can delete `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` simply and run a `sudo update-initramfs -k all -u`